# Does the Video Sequencer have any kind of comment strip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Almost like in code, you can write comments that are valuable for readibility but also are not included in the final compile. Markers wouldn't be sufficient, I'm thinking of paragraphs that can be placed in certain parts of the timeline. My idea is that I can write the script there and read off of it for the audio component. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Text strips placed in the same channel, have the channel enabled with reading and recording the audio, and then disable the channel when exporting the video. Afterwards you can, in the View menu, find the option to export them as subtitles - which might be useful if you're exporting to ex. YouTube.

Comment: Thank you, but is there anything that could be visible directly in the sequencer graph though? Only a certain amount of text can be visible on a strip in the graph. My idea is that I can get a big overview of all of the text in the graph, as far as writing the script itself within the graph. Is that too much to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Using subtitles will accomplish your "paragraphs placed in certain parts of the timeline" goal. There are Add-On options[0] for working with `.srt` and other subtitle formats. This also works for your Voice Over scripting goal and gets you closer to making your videos accessible.

Making your notes visible directly in the sequencer vs Properties might need configuration or reconsideration.

[0] [Subsimport](https://github.com/doakey3/Subsimport), e.g.